# Efficiently groupby of a sparse matrix in python

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, python-itertools, pandas-groupby

I have an extremely sparse matrix with ~10M rows (N) and ~1K columns (P). Every row has only one non-empty value, so there are N entries.
I also have an array of 10M non-unique values which are the "keys" I want to group by them my sparse matrix. Let's denote K the number of unique keys (~200K).

The result should be a sparse matrix with K rows and P columns, with N entries.

Applying pandas groupby function has an horrible performance for me and the output is not sparse. I tried to apply itertools.groupby but the loop takes too much time. I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I attach a code for replication of my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
N = 10000000
P = 1000
K = 200000
keys = np.random.choice(K, N)
row = [i for i in range(N)]
col = np.random.choice(P, N)
data = np.random.normal(loc = 100, scale = 2, size = N)
mat = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(N,P))
```

I will very much appreciate a code that will give me back a matrix/dataframe with of dimension K X P with N entries, the keys as an index.

Thanks a lot!
Alan

Comment: You've showed us how you made the matrix, but nothing about how you are trying to do the rest of the problem.  It would be good if you demonstrated the task with small arrays where you can show the results, and we can test them.  Worry about the large scale performance later.  If you aren't doing matrix multiplication the sparse matrix format might not useful.

Comment: Hi, you are right. I did state that I tried to use groupby or itertools.groupby but it was not efficient, but like both you and Paul Panzer below pointed, the correct way to do it was matrix multiplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like plain matrix multiplication to me. Note that the resulting matrix will have fewer than 10 million nonzeros because of key collisions. The last bit of the code identifies the keys, columns and multiplicities of those collisions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
N = 10_000_000
P = 1000
K = 200_000
keys = np.random.choice(K, N)
row = [i for i in range(N)]
col = np.random.choice(P, N)
data = np.random.normal(loc = 100, scale = 2, size = N)
mat = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(N,P))


import time

t0 = time.perf_counter()
from scipy import sparse

km = sparse.csc_matrix((np.ones(N,), keys, np.arange(N+1)), (K, N))
result = km @ mat
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'{t1-t0:.3f} seconds')

print(f'{result!r}')
print()

# identify collisions
t0 = time.perf_counter()
idctr = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones((N,), int), col, np.arange(N+1)), (N, P))
coll = km @ idctr
cidx = *map(np.flatnonzero, map(coll.data.__eq__, range(2, 6))),
c2, c3, c4, c5 = map(np.searchsorted, 4 * (coll.indptr,), cidx, 4 * ('left',))
k2, k3, k4, k5 = map(coll.indices.__getitem__, cidx)
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'{t1-t0:.3f} seconds')
print(', '.join(map(str, map(len, (k2, k3, k4, k5)))), 'collisions of 2, 3, 4, 5 keys')
```

Sample output:

```
3.998 seconds
<200000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 9754546 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

4.110 seconds
237476, 3908, 54, 0 collisions of 2, 3, 4, 5 keys
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. Indeed, matrix multiplication is a great way to workaround the need for groupby. For the example I posted, your code runs perfectly well; for my example however, python runs out of memory (kernel dies) when trying to perform the following multiplication: result = km @ mat. What additional info can I provide you? I can't export the actual data due to privacy.
Thanks!

Comment: @alanarazi7 Are your actual data significantly larger than the fake data? N=10,000,000, P=1,000, K=200,000 runs no prob on my 8GB laptop.

Comment: Hi, good question. I'm working with N = 10,781,271, K = 362,074, P = 1,609. So I guess the size is not the issue. Things that are different in fake data are: [1] values of the variable 'data' might be less unique (in the use case I worked on, I would say it's not normal but binomial so the outcome is not continuous), [2] distribution of K - in the fake example most values in 'keys' have pretty much the same amount of non-zero entries, in my data I would say that there might be a few customers with a lot of non-zero entries. 
Are of any of these things very important?

Comment: @alanarazi7 Nope, there is nothing obvious. I just tried with your larger numbers, still no prob. Is your data matrix definitely the same format (scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)?

Comment: Hi. It is exactly the same format. The first input for the multiplication is "<10781271x1609 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 10781271 stored elements in COOrdinate format>" and the second input is "<362074x10781271 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 10781271 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>"/

Comment: By the way, the type is "scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix" and not "scipy.sparse.coo_matrix" as you asked, any chance it's related?

Comment: Ok, something which seems problematic - my "keys" matrix seems to be somehow wrong. When I use our example data it works as I expect, but when I tried to just apply the same logic over your code, when I try to transform it into a dataframe it says: "ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions"

Comment: For the `@` any `coo` matrix will be converted to `csr`.

Comment: @alanarazi7  Ok, so what do your `keys` look like? type? range of elements? shape? Without more information I can't help you.

Comment: My keys elements are (large) integers which represent user IDs. They are all 20 digits long, so int64 and not int32 like in the example I gave. They aren't a range and a value of K can be much larger than N.

Comment: @alanarazi7 In that case you have to translate them to a range. You can use `uniqe_keys, indices = np.unique(keys, return_inverse=True)` and then use `indices` instead of `keys`.  `unique_keys` maps indices back to your original keys.